# Unity Update Text on Gameobject initiated from script from other Gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am developing for the HoloLens and I Made an object that follows me around. This Gameobject is actually an UI Canvas with text in it which I set like this because i want to keep the original object as well. (Just like in the MS example):

```
 /// <summary>
/// The object to tag along set in the unity editor
/// </summary>
public GameObject ObjectToTagAlong;

/// <summary>
/// The instantiated object to tag along that follows you around.
/// </summary>
private GameObject instantiatedObjectToTagAlong;

 this.instantiatedObjectToTagAlong = GameObject.Instantiate(this.ObjectToTagAlong);
```

this instantiatedObject tags along just fine but now I want to update the Text on instantiatedObjectToTagAlong but have no idea how to do this. (I can very easily update the text on the 1st object but i want to do it this way)

Does anyone know how to update the text on a gameobject that is initiated from another GameObject?

Comment: Are you aware of the `GetComponent()` method? It sounds like what you need, unless you're actually trying to do something other than modifying a `Text` component on the instantiated GameObject.

Comment: Hhmm would that actually be able to filter for a specific text?

For example if i have a textfield called SuperText 2

Can i say 

Text SuperText2  << (Then assign the object in Unity) 


Text newUpdatedText= gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(SuperText2  )) as SuperText2;

And then newUpdatedText.Text = "New Text"

Comment: Er...if your component is of type `SuperText2`, then you might be able to do that - it'd clear up any ambiguity if you included a screenshot of your object hierarchy, and indicate what you're trying to modify.

Comment: Hey Serlite see my comment at Avariant. Maybe that hierarchy image will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on what Serlite commented with, you need to use `GetComponent` in combination with another script.

```
public class MyTextUpdater: MonoBehavior
{
public Text SuperText2;
}
```

Apply `MyTextUpdater` to your ObjectToTagAlong prefab (or `GameObject` if not a prefab) and, in the editor, set the value of SuperText2 to the Text object you want to update (typically this is a child of the ObjectToTagAlong GameObject).

Now anytime you want to update that Text object on your instance, instantiatedObjectToTagAlong, you can do this:

```
MyTextUpdater text = instantiatedObjectToTagAlong.GetComponent<MyTextUpdate>();
if (text!=NULL && text.SuperText2!=NULL) { /*do whatever you need to do on the text.SuperText2 object*/ }
```

**EDIT:**
When Unity instantiates a copy of a GameObject, it makes a "deep" copy of sorts, meaning that the copy will have the exact same structure of child GameObjects.

```
Original                                Copy
- Child A                               - Child A (copy)
- Child B              Instanitate =>   - Child B (copy)
- - Grandchild A                        - - Grandchild A (copy)
```

Each child is instantiated with it's own new copy.  On top of that, if Original has a MonoBehavior script that points to one of it's children (or grandchildren etc), Copy will have a script that points to the appropriately **copied** child.

```
MyTextUpdater [Original]                 MyTextUpdater [Copy]
- SuperText2 = Child B           =>       - SuperText2 = Child B (copy)
```

Regarding the question of why have the extra script (the MyTextUpdater script):

Original is just a GameObject.  In the editor you can see it has children, but that does not represent a class.  You can not do something like this in a script:

```
Original.ChildB.Text = "Hello World!";
```

in the same way, you can't do this:

```
Copy.ChildB.Text = "Hello Copy World!";
```

You could create code to iterate through all the children of the GameObject looking for a child with the correct name ("ChildB"), but that is inefficient and probably bad programming.
The better way is to create a script class that actually does give you access to the child as a field in that class.  And that is where the `MyTextUpdater` script comes in.

This would be invalid:

```
GameObject Copy = Instantiate(Original);
Copy.SuperText2.Text = "Some text here";
```

Copy does not have a field or method called SuperText2, or ChildB, or whatever you would call it.  But you could do this:

```
GameObject Copy = Instantiate(Original);
MyTextUpdater mtu = Copy.GetComponent<MyTextUpdater>();
mtu.SuperText2.Text = "Some text here";
```

Assuming of course that you applied the MyTextUpdater script to Original and made the right connections to the child text component.

Comment: But wouldn't this be the same as updating the text on ObjectToTagAlong; ? That does not seem to update the Text on the object that follows.

Comment: Not if done right.  If Text (the Text you set for the field "SuperText2') is a child of ObjectToTagAlong, when you `Instantiate` a new copy, the instance will have all the references updated for you to point to the new Text, now a child of the instance, instantiatedObjectToTagAlong.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was not able to work on this until now. I don't get why I would need another class for this? Wouldn't I just be able to get the text Component directly in the class where I set the new object? Because updating the original text won't work so even if I put it another class it won't update the new one. 

Here is an image of how the structure would look http://imgur.com/a/3QkSH maybe that can help. I set the script above and want to update the text where the instantiatedObjectToTagAlong is the WarningCanvas

Comment: I edited my answer to address.  Hopefully it will make it easier to understand why you would want to use a script like MyTextUpdater.

Comment: Thanks man this must have taken so much time. It made me understand the concept and it seems that I might need refactor quite a big amount of code for that to work everywhere but I tried it and it worked. SO again thanks!! :)